# Dealing with poison kafka messages in flink while keeping the order per partition

Tags: apache-flink

As far as I can tell, when deserializing objects using KafkaDeserializationSchema[T], my 3 options are to return T, return null (ignore the record) or throw an exception (shut down the task manager) [from: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#the-deserializationschema]. I have a requirement to stop processing subsequent messages on the topic where a poison message fails deserialization, but only until a human intervenes and makes a decision whether to ignore the message or replace it with a corrected one.

Has anyone had to deal with a similar requirement?

I was thinking about introducing a separate process function for dealing with converting an array of bytes to T, connecting a broadcast stream to it, and reacting to commands from a human operator in all instances of that operator. The problem here is that I can't figure out a way to pause reading from kafka while the system waits for a human to make a decision. I could throw exceptions and restart indefinitely, or I could keep reading from the topic and holding the incoming messages in the state, but I'm worried about additional CPU usage and balooning state for options 1 and 2 respectively.

Any thoughts anyone? Thanks!